# Access public folder of Laravel in CSS file

Tags: css, laravel-5, directory

Newbie question as stated above. How do I access the public folder of laravel in `.css` file? I have a custom `css` and I want to get the url of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the `asset()` or `public_path()` functions there, they will not get called from a css file but you can use the traditional way to access file like this

```
../css/want_to_import.css
```

This is the only way you can access a file in a css file, unless you're writting your css dynamically then possibilities are different.

Answer (score 0):

If your domain points to your public folder, you can reference it using /

Let's imagine you want to display a JPG file as a background image.

> public/image/background.jpg

In your CSS, you can use `background-image:url('/images/background.jpg')`